# Looking for Javascript coding challenge Websites. Can you guys help?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, javascript, mobile-automation

I really need to improve my JS coding (currently learning ES6) as it would be great for my automation Testing.  I would like to take a daily coding challenge (min 30 days) but I'm having difficulty finding any decent websites free websites.

Can anyone help?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With a simple search on the internet you can get a bunch of such websites.

Here are a few I found,

https://www.freecodecamp.org/ - This one I'm also using to learn JS.

https://www.java5cript.com/code-challenges

https://www.jschallenger.com/

https://javascript30.com/

Comment: thank you.  